# Hive: how to display and store a 20-digit integer without using scientific notation?

Tags: hadoop, hive

Dealing with a 20-digit account number: 21345698778965412365

Since `bigint` can only deal with number less than 19-digit, casting it to `bigint` results in a wrong number.

I tried to cast it to `string` but scientific notation appears and both `string` and `decimal` lose the last digits.

So how to display and store it without scientific notation？ Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Note: what you see depends on the actual tool you're using to query Hive

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks for your reply. I tried `HUE`, command-line, and directly insert the result into a table and then `select ... from table`. All failed..

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks for your reply. I see~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `DECIMAL(precision, scale)` data type, particularly `DECIMAL(20,0)` or just `DECIMAL(20)` for your case.
`precision` parameter represents the total number of digits that the value may represent, regardless of a fraction, and `scale` parameter represents the number of fractional digits that the value will have. Since you need no fraction, you set it to `0`. `DECIMAL(precision, 0)` is equivalent to `DECIMAL(precision)`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried `SELECT cast(21345698778965412365 as decimal(20)) ;` and `SELECT cast(21345698778965412365 as decimal(20,0)) ;`, but they both return `21345698778965414000`.  The last digits become 0.

Comment: now it depends on which data type you are trying to cast during `select`. if it is `string`, the cast would work.

Comment: if you need to create a table keeping 20-digit integer values, you need to specify `decimal(20)` in the table schema itself. after that, you may load your 20-digit integers into that table and select from table without any loss